# Thingsboard RestApi - returns 500error

Tags: thingsboard

I am working to get data from the Things board ( version 2.3.2) using REST API. The Thingsboard server is installed on AWS instance. When I use the Swagger UI, on my instance, to get the attributes of my device/asset, I always get the following error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-06-28T14:33:26.909+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/plugins/telemetry/ASSET/b3f29330-890d-11e9-ab17-81c76d54ccfd/keys/attributes"
}

The /var/log/thingsboard/thingsboard.log file shows a Java null pointer exception:
2019-06-28 14:33:26,908 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8081-exec-24] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in conte
xt with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.security.model.token.JwtTokenFactory.parseAccessJwtToken(JwtTokenFactory.java:113)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.security.auth.jwt.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:42)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecuri
tyConfigurerAdapter.java:503)
```

I get the same error when I use any of the REST API. Please note that there are no authentication/token issues.

I did not find any references in the documentation or github issues. Is there something else that I should be doing or is this a bug?

Comment: check this file at this line.   JwtTokenFactory.parseAccessJwtToken(JwtTokenFactory.java:113

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when I using /api/device API for creating device.
I used the value of key "refreshToken" in authentication header . I replaced it with the value of the key "token" and every thing works fine.

NOTE : when you call this API for getting JWT-token :

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"username":"tenant@thingsboard.org", "password":"tenant"}' 'http://THINGSBOARD_URL/api/auth/login'
```

it gives you two things:

```
{"token":"$YOUR_JWT_TOKEN", "refreshToken":"$YOUR_JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN"}
```

you should use "$YOUR_JWT_TOKEN" .